# Click on one view in a position in List and other view at different position automatic working?

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I am using a custom check Box in a list with Base Adapter.
Problem is that when I click on a check Box for unchecked then a other check Box automatic be Unchecked.
Suppose I Click on a check Box at 0 position then a other check Box with 5th position will automatic Unchecked.

```
          public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final  ViewHolder  holder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.socket_layer, null);
    }
        holder.checkBox = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_SocketFilter);
        holder.filter_name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.filter_name);

        holder.filter_name.setText(rowItems.get(position));
      holder.checkBox.setTag(position);
           holder.onoff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
         int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
             if(!selectedItems.get(position)){
                 selectedItems.put(position,true);    
                 if(PrefUtils.socketCheck[position].equals(true))
                 {
                         holder.onoff.setImageResource(R.drawable.offf);                         
                     PrefUtils.socketCheck[position]=false;                       
                     selectedItems.delete(position);


                     }
                   else if(PrefUtils.socketCheck[position].equals(false)){
                     holder.onoff.setImageResource(R.drawable.onnn);                  
                     PrefUtils.socketCheck[position]=true;                   
                     selectedItems.delete(position);
                 }
             }else{
             selectedItems.delete(position);
         }
         }
     });
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: Find the below answer.

Comment: Accept the answer, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify your code some thing like this.

1. Before setting click listener, add the position as tag in onOff button

   `holder.onoff.setTag(position);`
2. And in `onClick()`

   `int position = (Integer) v.getTag();`

and after that use this position variable inside `onClick()` for operations.

Comment: Mean, what is happening?

Comment: same, when click on 0 position then 5 Th position automatic unchecked.

Comment: I checked position by toast, position is showing correct by toast, but icon  of select and deselect are showing same on position number 1 n 5, 2 n 6 and its so on....

Comment: @DalvinderSingh What is this PrefUtils[]?

Comment: have you skype? dalvindersingh47f add me please?

Comment: PreUtils is class that contains static values.

Comment: @DalvinderSingh Sorry for late reply. You need to define one boolean variable inside your data class. And set it to checkbox. If possible post the code of your data class.

Comment: But I am checking Boolean value for every check box.

Comment: Yes, you are checking but you need to set it to checkboxes also, to avoid your situation of multi selection.

Comment: I have less repution for chat.

Comment: have you any other resource for chat?

Comment: Now see. Whether you can chat or not?

Comment: I need 20 reputation for chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97846/discussion-between-dalvinder-singh-and-nigam-patro).

Answer (score 1):

I have used this code in unchecking some checkbox.You may give it a try:
My XMl File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sudiproy.checkboxtutorial.MainActivity">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/ch_android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/ch_ios"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="iOS"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/ch_windows"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Windows"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my Java file:

```
package com.example.sudiproy.checkboxtutorial;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CheckBox chAndroid,chiOS,chWindows;
    private Button submit;
    private CheckBox checkBox1;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        chAndroid= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.ch_android);
        chiOS= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.ch_ios);
        chWindows=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.ch_windows);
        submit= (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(chAndroid.isChecked()){
                    chWindows.setChecked(false);

                }



            }
        });

    }
}
```